# HowTo: Call method: renderPartial() - statically?

Tags: static, call, yii, instance

How can I call this method in Yii Framework:

```
$this->renderPartial(string $fileNameToRenderData, bool $wheaterToReturnOrEchoDirectly);
```

Statically, like this:

```
GodForbiddenClassName::renderPartial(string $fileNameToRenderData, bool $wheaterToReturnOrEchoDirectly);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You might want to look at [renderInternal](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseController#renderInternal-detail) which I've used in custom class functions, etc. It can be called like:

```
$ccc = new CController('context');
$html = $ccc->renderInternal($view_file_string, array('data'=>$data), true);
```

Comment: You wont be able to call `renderInternal` inside console command using `CController->renderInternal` because console has no idea what is a controller. Your best bet will be `renderFile`

Comment: ERROR: Non-static method CBaseController::renderInternal() should not be called statically

Comment: Updated answer to show how to avoid the error. Hopefully this method would still work for the OP, it works fine for me and can be used in both web app and/or console app. You could use [renderFile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CConsoleCommand#renderFile-detail) instead, and might be better if you are exclusively using this in a console app.

Answer (score 9):

i have to use render partial in model, i had code like this

```
    public function sendEmail(){
        $emailTemplate = new EmailTemplate();
        $message = $emailTemplate->getEmailTemplate(EmailTemplate::AGENT_CONTACT_REFFER);
        $message = $emailTemplate->replaceConstantWithValues($this->agent,$message);
        $message = $emailTemplate->replaceConstantWithValues($this->contact,$message);
        //$message = $emailTemplate->replaceConstantWithValues($this->contact->notes,$message);
        $message = str_replace("[CONTACT_NOTES]", Yii::app()->controller->renderPartial('application.views.note._notes', array('notes'=>$this->contact->notes,'showLinks'=>false),true),$message);
        $message = $emailTemplate->replaceConstantWithValues($this,$message);

        $email = Yii::app()->email;
        $email->from = $this->referringAgent->email;
        $email->to = $this->agent->email;
        $email->subject = "An agent has referred a contact to you";
        $email->message = $message;
        $email->send();
    }
```

Here i have used Yii::app()->controller->renderPartial

Comment: This will only work when a controller is present. If you try to send email with this function out of a cron job or console application, this will fail.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that this is impossible, since rendering is performed representations "on behalf" of the controller (or successor CBaseController)

But, in console application mode you can use this:

```
CConsoleCommand->renderFile()
```

See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CConsoleCommand

Comment: Can a Commando like me re-instanciate the Controller (CBaseController) so I'll somehow be able do call it statically through another class or what(tf)ever?

Comment: See source of renderFile function: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CConsoleCommand#renderFile-detail

Comment: In fact, rendering is reduced to these lines:
`extract($_data_,EXTR_PREFIX_SAME,'data');`
and 
`ob_start(); ob_implicit_flush(false); require($_viewFile_); return ob_get_clean();`

Answer (score 1):

[Check this yii wiki article](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/556/email-template-functionality-with-manage-content-from-database/) written by me .. :)

====>>> $emailTemplate = $this->renderPartial('template/templatecontact',array(),true); //Getting email template content

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.